# Additive White Gaussian Noise Java in dB

Tags: java, matlab, audio, gaussian, noise

I am trying to add AWGN to my audio file. I convert my wav file to byte array. I am trying to add 10dB AWGN to this array. In matlab there is imnoise which adds AWGN to image. In java is there any library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @macduff: That does't look like it'll do Gaussian white noise.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need the [additive Gaussian white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) output similar to that of Matlab's [`imnoise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html) function, this is the extent of the code that you need to implement in Java:

```
B = A+MU+STD*randn(size(A))
```

where `A` is your input data, `B` is your output of the same size, `MU` is the mean of the noise, and `STD` is the standard deviation. Independent and identically distributed (IID) Gaussian white noise is added to each component of `A`. This calculation needs to be done in floating point (as many of Matlab's image processing routines are).

The [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) function produces normal random variates. You can use [`java.util.Random.nextGaussian()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29) to produce these. If you need some extra speed, try a Java implementation of the [Mersenne Twister algorithm](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got the question correctly. Ist [that](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/signals/WhiteNoise.html) the thing your are looking for and then just regulate the db over whatever player you are using?

Comment: This generates noise at certain amplitude. I have a byte array. How can I adjust the dB?

Comment: If [this is the code] for the linked class, then I don't think that it actually implements Gaussian white noise. It implements some form of uniform noise. I don't think that it's even really white, but the output could be used to produce it (it's barely more than a call to `Math.random()`). The terms Gaussian noise and white noise are often misused so I'm not sure what the asker requires.

Comment: As I said before i'm not that sure either where the question ist going but if there is a byte array you can pack that into AudioData ect. making an AudioInputstream out of it. Careful you might hafe to write a wav header so the inputstream understands what it gets. And then have the java sound api to control volume over FloatControl.

Comment: `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
FloatControl gainControl = 
    (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
gainControl.setValue(//some dB value to increase or decrease);
clip.start();`